# Spring Security OAuth2 client with authorization_code grant - How to handle token request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a Spring Boot application using version 2.3.4 with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-security` dependencies.

I am trying to implement the [JIRA Tempo plugin OAuth support](https://tempo-io.github.io/tempo-api-docs/).

I have it partially working using the following properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tempo.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tempo.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tempo.client-id=<the-client-id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tempo.client-secret=<the-client-secret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tempo.provider=tempo

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tempo.authorization-uri=https://mycompany.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/ac/io.tempo.jira/oauth-authorize/?access_type=tenant_user
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tempo.token-uri=https://api.tempo.io/oauth/token/
```

and this config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(expressionInterceptUrlRegistry -> expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login();
    }
```

When I access http://localhost:8080, it redirects to JIRA/Tempo and shows the approval dialog there to grant access to the Tempo data for my application. I can grant access, but after that, it just redirects again to that page instead of showing my own application.

With debugging, I noticed that there is a redirect to http://localhost:8080/?code=.... but Spring Security is not handling that. What else do I need to configure?

I also tried to set some breakpoints in `DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient`, but they are never hit.

UPDATE:

I changed the `redirect-uri` to be:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tempo.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
```

(and I changed the Redirect URIs setting in Tempo to `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/tempo`).

This now redirects back to my localhost, but it fails with `authorization_request_not_found`.

UPDATE 2:

The reason for the `authorization_request_not_found` seems to be mismatch in `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request)` between what is in the `authorizationRequests` and the `stateParameters`.

[image: debugger screenshot]

Note how one ends with `=` and the other with `%3D`, which makes them *not* match. It is probably no coincidence that the URL encoding of `=` is `%3D`. It is unclear to me if this is something that is a Spring Security problem, or a problem of the Tempo resource server, or still a misconfiguration on my part.

Comment: Did you add token uri?

Comment: Did you understand the root cause for this? I see the exact same issue and not sure if its a bug in spring security or something that should be fixed on the server.

Comment: Are you also using JIRA Tempo as auth server? Because the root problem here was that they had a bug causing the double encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect-uri` property should not point to the root of your application, but to the processing filter, where the code after redirect is processed.

Best practice for you would be to leave the `redirect-uri` alone for the time being. Then it will default to `/login/oauth2/code/*` and this Url is handled by `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: If I comment out the redirect-uri property, then there is a startup failure `redirectUriTemplate cannot be empty`